# A proof on infimum property

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Suppose that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are nonempty sets with $A_2 \subset A_1$ of real numbers that are bounded below. I want to show that $\inf A_1 \leq \inf A_2$

I managed to do the opposite, that is $\inf A_2 \leq \inf A_1$ and not sure what went wrong in my proof

> Let $x \in A_2$, then because $A_2$ is bounded below there exists a number $y$ such that
>
> $y \leq x$ for all $x \in A_2$
>
> $A_2$ is nonempty, so by the greatest lower bound property that there exists a number $y^*$ such that $y \leq y^* \leq x$
>
> Now let $x \in A_2 \subset A_1$, then since $A_1$ is bounded below we have $y \leq x$ for each $x \in A_1$. By the greaest lower bound property, there exists a number $z^*$ such that $y \leq z^* \leq x$, but recall $y^* \in A_1$ is an lower bound for some $x$, so we must have $y^* \leq z^* \implies \inf A_2 \leq \inf A_1$

My motivation for proving this come from proving that if $P \subset Q$, then $L(f,P) \leq L(f,Q)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last paragraph doesn’t make a lot of sense: yes, $A_1$ has a greatest lower bound, say $z^*$, and $z^*\le x$ for all $x\in A_2$, simply because $A_2\subseteq A_1$, but that doesn’t tell you anything about the relationship between $z^*$ and $y^*=\inf A_2$.

In any case you’re making it much harder than necessary. Just observe that if $u$ is a lower bound for $A_1$, then $u\le x$ for all $x\in A_1$, so trivially $u\le x$ for all $x\in A_2$, since $A_2\subseteq A_1$. Now let $u=\inf A_1$ be the greatest lower bound for $A_1$; in particular $u$ is **a** lower bound for $A_1$, so by the previous observation $u$ is a lower bound for $A_2$ as well. By definition, then, $u\le\inf A_2$, since $\inf A_2$ is the largest of all lower bounds for $A_2$.

Comment: Now i feel like an idiot.